# Definite integral of $\sin(x^3)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am having trouble integrating $\sin\left(\, x^{3}\,\right)$ from $x = -10$ to
$x = 10$. I have tried $u$ substitution but is doesn't seem to work out.  By the way the question is $\sin\left(\, x^{3}\,\right)$ not $\left[\,\sin\left(\,x\,\right)\,\right]^3$.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to integrate $\sin\left(x^3\right)$ since there is no solution to $\sin\left(x^2\right)$. Unless there is an $x^2$ sitting in front of it, there is no possibility of you solving this with a $u$-substition.

Comment: It is possible that there is no antiderivative expressible in terms of trig functions, logs, or exponentials. The function you mention is very symmetric, so evaluating the *definite* integral can be approached geometrically.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**.  I don't believe you can do this integral by "ordinary" methods.  But. . .

- what is special about the interval from $-10$ to $10$?
- what is special about the function $\sin(x^3)$?

Comment: Thanks alot! I ended up using properties of definite integrals to solve this.

Comment: Did you get zero as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\color{#66f}{\large\int_{-10}^{10}\sin\left(\, x^{3}\,\right)\,{\rm d}x = 0}
$$

> Just make the change $\displaystyle{x \mapsto -x}$ and the result follows immediately.

$\displaystyle{\sin\left(\, x^{3}\,\right)}$ is an odd function of $\displaystyle{x}$
!!!.